# How do I Create Hive External table on top of ECS S3 object storage using "S3a//" protocol

Tags: hadoop, amazon-s3, hive, cloudera-cdp

I am trying to create Hive external table using Beeline on top of S3 object storage using "S3a//" scheme.I have followed the official cloudera documentation and configured the below properties.

1. fs.s3a.access.key
2. fs.s3a.secret.key
3. fs.s3a.endpoint

I am able to run `hadoop fs -Dfs.s3a.access.key=<access_key> -Dfs.s3a.secret.key=<secret_key> -Dfs.s3a.endpoint=<host_port> -ls s3a://<bucket_name>/dir/` successfully and able to see the directories. So I know my credentials, bucket access, and overall Hadoop setup is valid.

However, when I attempt to access the same s3 resources from ***hive(Beeline)***, e.g. run ***CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE** statements using LOCATION 's3a://[bucket-name]/dir/'*, it fails.

Configurations

```
set fs.s3a.access.key=<access_key>; 
set fs.s3a.secret.key=<secret_key>; 
set fs.s3a.endpoint=<host:port>;
```

Query

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE NAME_TEST_S3(name string, age int) ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' STORED AS TextFile LOCATION 's3a://<bucket_name>/dir/'
```

I am getting below error.

> ERROR : FAILED: Execution error, return code 40000 from
> org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.ddl.DDLTask.  MetaException(message:Got
> exception: java.nio.file.AccessDeniedException <bucket_name>:
> org.apache.hadooop.fs.s3a.auth.NoAuthWithAWSException: No AWS
> Credentials provided by TemporaryAWSCredentialsProvider SimpleAWSCredentialsProvider EnvironmentVariableCredentialsProvider IAMInstanceCredentialsProvider : com.amazonaws.sdkClientException: Unable to load AWS Credentials from environment variables (AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID (or AWS_ACCESS_KEY) and AWS_SECRET_KEY (or AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY)) (state=08S01, code=40000)

**Note : I am using CDH-7.1.6 , Hive 3.1.3 and S3 object storage. I am able to access the same s3 resources using hadoop fs as well as using spark scala read api**

Anyone have any idea what's missing from this equation?

Comment: You should set these properties in `core-site.xml` on all the HDFS, Hive, and Spark clients rather than `set` per session